# get_Error_BPAAsimovNotReachedRetrying() not found when creating/validating cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to create a standalone Service Fabric cluster using 5.4.145.9494 SDK bits and when running `.\TestConfiguration.ps1 .\ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json` with no changes to the downloaded SDK whatsoever I'm getting following error:

> Test Config failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One or
>   more errors occurred. ---> System.MissingMethodExce ption: Method not
>   found: 'System.String
>   System.Fabric.Strings.StringResources.get_Error_BPAAsimovNotReachedRetrying()'.
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Common.StandaloneSettingsValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.IsJsonConfigModelValid(StandAloneInstallerJson
>   Model config)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.AnalyzeClusterSetup(String
>   configPath, String cabPath, Boolean usingClusterManifest,
>   FabricPackageType fabricPackageType)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.BpaAnalyzeClusterSetup(String
>   clusterConfigPat h, String fabricPackagePath)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.TestConfig(String
>   clusterConfigPath, String fabricPackagePath )    at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String System.Fabric.Strings.StringRe
>   sources.get_Error_BPAAsimovNotReachedRetrying()'.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Common.StandaloneSettingsValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.IsJsonConfigModelValid(StandAloneInstallerJson
>   Model config)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.AnalyzeClusterSetup(String
>   configPath, String cabPath, Boolean usingClusterManifest,
>   FabricPackageType fabricPackageType)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.d__3.MoveNext()<---

The same error is printed when trying to use `createservicefabriccluster.ps1`.

I'm trying it on a Windows Server 2012R2 machine. Interestingly, the same works just fine on another Windows 10 machine. There are other differences (Windows Server 2012 R2 machine is in *secure* environment with a bunch of access policies around network, disk access, etc.) but it's hard to tell what's actually causing validation to fail with a message like that ...

My question: How do I get pass that "MissingMethodException" noise and learn the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that's the exception you get when the machine is already part of a previously defined standalone, non-Dev cluster. Running `.\cleanFabric.ps1` made it work again.

Somebody should make the error message better ...